# Multithreaded EF code could use optimization

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I've got a sync method that compares a list of items from a web service, and syncs a local copy on our database.

This code works, and runs fine, but I have a strong feeling it could be optimised. We are dealing with 200,000 items, each which have 10-15 associated tables, so it's not a small amount of work, but usually takes about 30-60 mins to complete (more if there are more updated items than usual). It does appropriately use all cores, no issues there.

This code removes removed items.

```
var updatedListings = await _listingFeedService.GetListingsAsync();
            Object lockContext = new Object();
            var counter = 0; //Save changes every 300 listings
            var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1
            };

            //1.- Delete sold listings
            var soldListings = _listingRepo.GetSoldListings(updatedListings);
            Parallel.ForEach(soldListings, parallelOptions, (sl) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    lock (lockContext)
                    {
                        _listingRepo.DeleteByMlsId(sl);
                        counter++;
                        if (counter > 100)
                        {
                            _listingRepo.Save();
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    syncReport.AppendLine($"{System.DateTime.Now} - ListingId: {sl} Status:Error | Error: { e.Message}");
                }
            });
            _listingRepo.Save();
```

This code inserts new items

```
//3.- Save the new listings
            var newListings = _listingRepo.GetNewListings(updatedListings);
            counter = 0;
            Parallel.ForEach(newListings, parallelOptions, newListingMlsId =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     Listing listingToUpdate;
                     listingToUpdate = _listingFeedService.GetListingByMlsIdAsync(newListingMlsId).Result;

                     lock (lockContext)
                     {
                         _listingRepo.Add(listingToUpdate);
                         if (listingToUpdate.MlsId != 0)
                         {
                             counter++;
                             if (counter > 50)
                             {
                                 _listingRepo.Save();
                                 counter = 0;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                     syncReport.AppendLine($"{System.DateTime.Now} - ListingId: {newListingMlsId} Status:Error | Error: { e.Message}");
                 }
             });
            _listingRepo.Save();
```

Comment: This would be more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, will delete

Comment: Well, as it is now, it does belong to code review. On the other hand, if you have specific problem and need help with it, then yes, it can be asked here, but you need to pinpoint the exact problem you're trying to solve. Makes sense?

Comment: Where is the multithreaded code? All the work I see is inside a `lock` statement which makes the whole thing serial.

Comment: The GetListingByMlsIdAsync does a lookup and gets the data from the web service

Comment: I suppose the deletion portion doesn't need to be in a Parallel foreach, huh. Good point

Comment: I think you could speed it up considerably if you get the `listingsToUpdate` (plural) in one query up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure and pass all of the items to be deleted to it. This will do the whole deletion in one trip to the database.

For the insertion of new listings use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx).